# Set fixed screen size HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html page built for work perfectly at the screen resolution 1024px x 705px, on iPad (it's and html that get's launched in another app).

I need to set-up a CSS or JS rule, to view it on desktop client (like chrome), like is on iPad and 1024px x 705px resolution.

Using the "Inspector" the site looks great, but i need a kind-a-like preset to view it at this resolution without opening it.

Setting via CSS height and width of body didn't work. The page is bootstrap made.

Comment: a demo on jsfiddle would be good

Comment: Chrome's inspector isn´t reliable for resolutions, you can use pages like this:http://testsize.com/

Comment: http://bit.ly/1RaNIl5 this is the site

Comment: and this is the way i need to look like http://bit.ly/1Z1Lety

Comment: What should happen if the desktop screen is larger or smaller? The site should scale up or get fixed at the desired size?

Comment: the site should stay fixed at 1024px x 705px, not caring about the screen size